# CLion/CMake can find SDL in one project, but not another

Tags: c++, macos, cmake, sdl, clion

I have two C++ projects in SDL, both using SDL. For whatever reason, one of these projects can find SDL just fine. For the other, I can write code as if SDL was found- with autocompletion and everything- but when it comes to building the project, I am informed that `fatal error: 'SDL2/SDL.h' file not found`.

The CMakeLists.txt files of both projects are basically identical.

CMakeLists.txt for the project that doesn't work:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.12)
project(Snake)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)

include_directories(.)

find_package(SDL2 REQUIRED)

add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME}
    main.cpp
    SnakeBlock.cpp
    SnakeBlock.h
    SnakeGame.cpp
    SnakeGame.h
    SnakeBoard.cpp
    SnakeBoard.h)

target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} ${SDL2_LIBRARY})
```

And CMakeLists.txt for the project that does work:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.12)
project(Tetris)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)

include_directories(.)

find_package(SDL2 REQUIRED)

add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME}
    Game.cpp
    Game.hpp
    main.cpp
    Playfield.cpp
    Playfield.hpp
    Tetromino.cpp
    Tetromino.hpp)

target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} ${SDL2_LIBRARY})
```

And for both projects, SDL2 appears under the "External Libraries" section on the right sidebar, under Header Search Paths.

What gives?

Comment: Does the second (successfull) project use statement `#include <SDL2/SDL.h>`? As for correctness of CMake script, you probably forgot a line `include_directories(${SDL2_INCLUDE_DIR})`. "Probably" - because CMake itself isn't shipped with a script `FindSDL2.cmake` which searches SDL2. But when use `find_package()`, `XXX_LIBRARY` variable is usually paired with `XXX_INCLUDE_DIR` (or `XXX_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES`) variable.

Comment: @Tsyvarev It does. I fixed this problem in a rather crude manner by taking a line from the cache file of the project where it does work and pasting it into the cache file of the project where it doesn't.